# Win2D’s CanvasControl’s text is jittery with certain screen resolutions

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win2d

More precisely, when I use certain display scales in Windows (those that don’t produce perfect 1:1 pixel layout. 150%, 175%, etc), the text doesn’t always redraw itself in the exact same position during every redraw. It is as if it dances a bit. However, if I scale the display perfectly (100% or 200%, for example) the effect is nonexistent.

Is there a fix for this? I spent so much time developing a custom text editor with Win2D’s CanvasControl being used draw the UI text, then discover this. I absolutely cannot continue development under these circumstances, as I am not aware of a better alternative to Win2D’s CanvasControl for presenting text for a custom text editor.

Any advice helps! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

UWP is optimized for high resolution. The unit used is effective pixels (epx). In different resolutions, the application will scale accordingly.

In order to apply consistent performance at various resolutions, there is a very important concept:

> The sizes, margins, and positions of UI elements should always be in multiples of 4 epx in your UWP apps.

So you can check your app and resize text and controls to fit this principle.

See more in this document: [Introduction to UWP app design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/basics/design-and-ui-intro)